# Cucumber : Size of features

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, bdd

Im new to testing with cucumber and have a question regarding the size of a 'Feature'.

Assume you can add a collection of items to a list and do the usual CRUD , is it preferred to create one feature for this complete set of CRUD actions or a feature for each?

What is the preferred/accepted method ?

At what point does an action become a feature itself ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My criterion for when a feature becomes a feature is when an end user of the product will find it important.

Code size, # of classes involved, #of actions required, ..., etc have nothing to do with this consideration, since it is primarily a communication tool between the developer and the user/customer.

Since very few users get exited about CRUD operations on a list (unless it is for a list of people getting backstage passes for their favorite bands tour) I would guess this is too small for a feature.

It all depends who your users/customers are of course. If you create a API for the next generation persistence framework, it is absolutely appropriate.

Comment: I like your methodology of defining a feature : Something a user find important.

Comment: I have to hammer that point every day in my team. I find we tend to think to much internal in the cade and forget sometimes who we're doing it all for...